# Haskell: Non-strict boolean operations

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is there anyway to define a function like the following in Haskell?

```
or True      True      = True
or True      undefined = True
or True      False     = True
or undefined True      = True
or undefined False     = undefined
or undefined undefined = undefined
or False     True      = True
or False     undefined = undefined
or False     False     = False
```

I don't currently have a use case for it (though I'd be interested in one), I'm just interested if it's possible.

Comment: Is this lazy evaluation or your haskell interpretation of three-valued logic?

Comment: `undefined` isn't a value; it's the absence of a value. Therefore, you cannot "check if it is undefined", so you have to choose: number 1, 6 and 8 or number 4, 5, 6; you can't have both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your evaluation order (the order in which you inspect values) you can write a lazy version:

```
Prelude> True || undefined
True
Prelude> undefined || True
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

Prelude> :t or
or :: [Bool] -> Bool

Prelude> or [True, undefined]
True
```

in fact, the default definition in Haskell will behave like this, since Haskell is a lazy language.

However, there's no way to "skip" an undefined value, without looking at the value first, which will evaluate it to a bottom, which causes your expression to be undefined.

Remember that lazy values are presents with ghosts inside them:

[image]

If you look inside the box, a ghost might get you.

If checking for bottoms is important (e.g. as part of a testsuite) you can treat them as exceptions, [and intercept them](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ChasingBottoms). But you wouldn't do that in a pure function.

Comment: For reference, the box with the ghost comes from Edward Yang's highly recommended blog post http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/the-haskell-heap/

Answer (score 15):

This is not possible in standard Haskell, but can be done with an unsafe trick, implemented in the [lub](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lub) library by Conal Elliott.

Basically, you write two functions:

```
orL True _ = True
orL False x = x

orR = flip orL
```

and then you can define `or a b` to be the `lub` (the least upper bound with respect to "definedness" order) of `orL a b` and `orR a b`.

Operationally, it runs both computations in parallel and chooses the first one that succeeds, killing the other.

Even though that works as you proposed, it has important disadvantages. First of all, `lub` is only safe if its arguments agree (equal unless bottom). If you take `lub True False`, the result will be non-deterministic, thus violating purity! Second, the performance overhead of running both computations in parallel can become dominating in some conditions (try computing a `foldr or False` of a large list, for example!).

Comment: why `lub True False` shall be non-deterministic? intuitively, it should return `undefined`.

Comment: @EarthEngine, because that is not monotonic in definedness order and so is impossible to implement. In particular, `f False` is not allowed to be less defined than `f undefined`. If you take `f = lub True`, you get your example.

Comment: So is it possible to write `lub' :: Bool -> Bool -> Maybe Bool` such that `lub' True False == Nothing`?

Comment: No, not possible because you'll still want `lub' True undefined = Just True` and that's incomparable with `Nothing` (both are fully-defined, but different values). I'm clearly not the best person to explain this and I advise you ask a separate question or turn to literature. "Denotational semantics" and perhaps "Domain theory" should be good starting search queries.